# Why script behaves differently using different webhost?

Tags: php, html, json, web-hosting

I have a well functioning script using infinity free webhosting. The same script won't work on Awardspace webhosting for some reasons. Both host enable php.

The error message that I get:

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent [...] line 2

Warning: file_get_contents(http://ipinfo.io/37.76.66.143/json): failed to open stream: Connection refused in [...] line 52

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by [..] line 72
```

The script start like (line 1-3):

```
<?php
session_start(); 
?>
```

row (51-53):

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
$locationData = $details->city;
```

row (68-75):

```
if($_SESSION['username'] == "admin")
{
    header('Location: adminPage.php');
}
else
{
    header('Location: landingPage.php');
}
```

Comment: Your hosting is filtering traffic to ipinfo. Probably because they dont trust them.

Comment: Thank you. But even if I remove those 3 lines, the other 2 errors remain. Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps you have errors turned on on one of the servers